# Unknow error in the code

Tags: apache-flex

I have create a form with the validator. Every time the code run to the label.text or function related to label.text the following error pop up. Is the following error mean the validator have bug or the default value of the label.text is wrong??

---

```
ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property Text not found on spark.components.TextInput and there is no default value.
    at mx.validators::Validator/getValueFromSource()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\validators\Validator.as:980]
    at mx.validators::Validator/validate()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\validators\Validator.as:940]
    at mx.validators::Validator/triggerHandler()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\validators\Validator.as:1167]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at mx.core::UIComponent/dispatchEvent()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:13152]
    at spark.components.supportClasses::SkinnableTextBase/textDisplay_valueCommitHandler()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\supportClasses\SkinnableTextBase.as:2743]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at mx.core::UIComponent/dispatchEvent()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:13152]
    at spark.components::RichEditableText/set text()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\RichEditableText.as:2115]
    at spark.components.supportClasses::SkinnableTextBase/set text()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\supportClasses\SkinnableTextBase.as:1400]
    at spark.components::TextInput/set text()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\TextInput.as:280]
    at productDetailComp/onNew()[C:\Users\School\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\FYPadminSideV3\src\productDetailComp.mxml:44]
    at productDetailComp/__newBut_click()[C:\Users\School\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\FYPadminSideV3\src\productDetailComp.mxml:314]
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the error says the property "Text" (with a capital T) is not found.  The `TextInput` has a `text` property with a lowercase "t".

It sounds like you have configured the `Validator` to verify the incorrect property name. That is, you're doing this:

```
<mx:Validator source="{myTextInput} property="Text" />
```

When it should be this:

```
<mx:Validator source="{myTextInput} property="text" />
```

Comment: run perfectly after I change it to the lower case.